# CodeIgniter - strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-password-hash

```
$query = $this->db->select('password')->get_where('members', array('email' => $this->input->post('email')));

if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
    if (password_verify($this->input->post('password'), $query->row(1))) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

I'm using the above code to verify user input password with hash from the database, and I'm using CodeIgniter which has the built in password_compat to make the functions work for versions less than 5.5.

The above should work, but I keep getting this error:

> Severity: Warning Message: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string,
>   object given Filename: compat/password.php Line Number: 220

What could be the issue here?

Thanks!

Comment: where do you call strlen()?

Comment: My guess is that your `strlen()` is being called in the `password_verify()` function.  I expect that the second parameter where you're using `$query->row(1)` is the problem.  Without knowing how your database object is built, my assumption is that `$query->row(1)` is sending an object containing a whole row, rather than a password or password hash string.

Comment: The error message is the answer of your question.Just open the file that it got error message.or look http://php.net/password_verify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get query result in variable and this is wrong use of

```
$query->row(1);
```

It would be

```
$rows=$query->row();
$rows->password;
```

check below code

```
$query = $this->db->select('password')->get_where('members', array('email' => $this->input->post('email')));

if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
    $rows=$query->row();// here you assign result to $rows variable
```

Check here how you pass your password variable as parameter

```
    if (password_verify($this->input->post('password'), $rows->password)) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Read  [Generating Query Results](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

Comment: I did the above, and I'm getting 2 more errors now:
Undefined property: CI_DB_pdo_result::$row
Trying to get property of non-object

Both are only notice errors though?

Comment: Ahhh little mistake by me it would be `$rows=$query->row();` not `$rows=$query->row;` i forget `()`

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `$query->row(1)` to `$query->row(0)->password`